# Работа с QSvgRenderer и Qr кодом

Tags: qt5, svg

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь отобразить Qr через класс наследника от QGraphicsSvgItem, в его конструкторе делаю:

```
QrCode qr = QrCode::encodeText(textQr.data(), QrCode::Ecc::MEDIUM);

QSvgRenderer *render = new QSvgRenderer;
render->load(QByteArray::fromStdString(qr.toSvgString(4)));
this->setSharedRenderer(render);
```

textQr это QByteArray с обычным тектом.
QrCode это класс вот отсюда https://github.com/nayuki/QR-Code-generator

В общем всё работает, но отображается как-то странно:

[image: Отображение]

На скрине у сцены выставлен персиковый фон.
Я конечно же переопределил boundingRect(). Проверял, размер QGraphicsSvgItem равен мною переопределённому boundingRect(), с этим всё нормально, но у рендера viewBox равен 47.5, при изменении его изменяется и этот белый фон QGraphicsSvgItem, и я в ступоре почему так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На этом скрине в методе paint я добавил следующие строки:

```
painter->setPen(QColor(Qt::darkBlue));
painter->drawRect(QRect(0, 0, renderer()->boundsOnElement(elementId()).width(), renderer()->boundsOnElement(elementId()).height()));
painter->setPen(QColor(Qt::red));
painter->drawRect(boundingRect());
```

В общем мне нужно как-то адекватно отобразить реальный контект qr кода в размер boundingRect() и я прошу в этом помочь. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Пробовал изменять viewbox у рендера, но для зума нужно его делить в несколько раз, при делении на 3 получилось почти что нужно, но при этом фон Qr кода расширился, игнорируя boundingRect.